# download and run Html code on iphone forbidden?

Tags: iphone, html, ios4

Apple says this can be a reason for rejection for any Iphone app:

No Interpreted Code You cannot create an app that downloads and executes code that was not present in the app bundle submitted to Apple.

Downloading and running Html code from my web service to iphone is forbidden ? Please no guessing but real experience.

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with displaying a webpage that performs a script.  I believe what Apple meant was that the app should not download an external binary that runs.

Comment: your name is quite dangerous sudo rm -rf :) serious..

Comment: Haha, I'm harmless. No worries. My name isn't.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple means the following with their rules:

**What you can do:**

- Run HTML code with Javascripts in a UIWebView
- Inject custom Javascript into a
  website
- Download HTML snippets to view in a
  UIWebView

**What you can't do:**

- Download an executable binary and run
  it. (wouldn't work as they're probably unsigned, but Apple rejects apps that do so anyway)